# Unable to connect to certain hosts from an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am running Ubuntu on an EC2 instance and certain, very particular hosts fail to reply to POST. For example when I run

`curl -v -L -I http://www.moneymanagement.com.au/`

from my local machine, I receive an immediate reply. However, the same command, run from EC2 times out.

> - About to connect() to www.moneymanagement.com.au port 80 (#0)
> - Trying 61.14.142.150... Connection timed out
> - couldn't connect to host
> - Closing connection #0 curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

However the same POST to Google and others returns immediately. Additionally, circumventing the name server avoids this problem:

`curl -v -L -I 141.101.124.53`

Replies without failure. What might be causing this behavior?

Edit: Here are the traceroute results.

```
traceroute to www.moneymanagement.com.au (61.14.142.150), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.96.72.3 (10.96.72.3)  0.345 ms  0.444 ms  0.556 ms
 2  ip-10-1-16-41.ec2.internal (10.1.16.41)  0.540 ms ip-10-1-28-41.ec2.internal (10.1.28.41)  0.390 ms ip-10-1-18-41.ec2.internal (10.1.18.41)  0.499 ms
 3  ip-10-1-29-14.ec2.internal (10.1.29.14)  0.667 ms ip-10-1-13-14.ec2.internal (10.1.13.14)  0.755 ms ip-10-1-29-14.ec2.internal (10.1.29.14)  0.865 ms
 4  216.182.224.120 (216.182.224.120)  2.872 ms 216.182.232.50 (216.182.232.50)  2.732 ms 216.182.224.211 (216.182.224.211)  2.580 ms
 5  100.64.2.195 (100.64.2.195)  1.680 ms 100.64.2.235 (100.64.2.235)  1.885 ms 100.64.2.247 (100.64.2.247)  2.098 ms
 6  100.64.0.50 (100.64.0.50)  364.049 ms 100.64.0.6 (100.64.0.6)  383.689 ms 100.64.0.24 (100.64.0.24)  403.813 ms
 7  * * *
 8  72.21.220.225 (72.21.220.225)  0.526 ms 72.21.222.148 (72.21.222.148)  1.056 ms 72.21.220.225 (72.21.220.225)  0.718 ms
 9  72.21.222.148 (72.21.222.148)  0.815 ms 205.251.245.64 (205.251.245.64)  0.839 ms 72.21.222.148 (72.21.222.148)  47.064 ms
10  gw3.lax1.asianetcom.net (206.223.115.40)  65.325 ms  65.297 ms  65.291 ms
11  te0-1-0-0-983.cr1.syd5.asianetcom.net (203.192.174.133)  202.111 ms  201.326 ms  201.273 ms
12  gi0-1-0.gw16.syd5.asianetcom.net (203.192.174.170)  201.375 ms te0-1-0-0-983.cr1.syd5.asianetcom.net (203.192.174.133)  200.736 ms gi0-1-0.gw16.syd5.asianetcom.net (203.192.174.170)  200.682 ms
13  gi0-1-0.gw16.syd5.asianetcom.net (203.192.174.170)  200.504 ms  200.922 ms *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Comment: What IP do you get when you try to do a nslookup of www.moneymanagement.com.au on the EC2 instance?

Comment: Server:         172.16.0.23
Address:        172.16.0.23#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.moneymanagement.com.au      canonical name = www.moneymanagement.com.au.cdn.cloudflare.net.
www.moneymanagement.com.au.cdn.cloudflare.net   canonical name = cf-ssl4857-protected-www.moneymanagement.com.au.cdn.cloudflare.net.
Name:   cf-ssl4857-protected-www.moneymanagement.com.au.cdn.cloudflare.net
Address: 141.101.126.52
Name:   cf-ssl4857-protected-www.moneymanagement.com.au.cdn.cloudflare.net
Address: 141.101.124.53

Answer (score 0):

The `connection timed out` error is where you should concentrate (assuming the IP address is the correct one for the host you intend to connect to.)  In order to establish an HTTP connection you will need:

- a web server listening on port 80 on the server
- a security group associated with the host instance that allows traffic over port 80 from your IP (more likely from all IPs)

Check that the web server is running on the instance (log in and run `ps -elf` and check for your web server process (e.g. `apache` or `nginx`).  Or check the web server error log to ensure that it started correctly.  Unless you have a funky configuration, it's likely listening on port 80.

Check the security group associated with the instance through the AWS console.  Is it the same as other instances that are working?  If not, chances are that's the problem, or if this is the only instance, then you'll need to allow traffic on port 80.

If the IP address is wrong, check your DNS settings (Route 53 on AWS if that's where you do DNS for your domain), or the IP address associated with any elastic IP associated with the instance.